# Error in NHibernate Session and HttpModule implementation

Tags: nhibernate, visual-studio-2005, asp.net-2.0, sample

Hello is nice to be a new member of the community and thanks for your help in advance.

I am starting to use NHibernate for my projects and is interesting. I found this sample that i managed to make work using Visual Studio 2005, Asp.net and the NHibernate binaries of the NHibernate-2.0.1.GA version.

NHibernate basic (Sample 1):
www.codegod.de/WebAppCodeGod/NHibernate-Tutorial-1---and-ASP-NET-AID25.aspx

I wanted to move further and implement good practices for my projects so i looked up for a better implementation and found this:

NHibernate Best Practices (Sample 2):
www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/NHibernateBestPractices.aspx?msg=3043520

So now I am trying to change a bit the basic sample project using only the BasicSample.Data.NHibernateSessionManager.cs (as a library class) and NHibernateSessionModule.cs (as a class in Web App_Code) both classes are provided on the second sample and now I am getting an error message on the class NHibernateSessionManager.cs :

session=session.OpenSession() "**Object Reference not set as an instance of the object**"

The project source in case you want to check it is [here](http://uploading.com/files/22d54m2b/NHibernateASPSample3.rar)

I would like to get some help about this error, but maybe would be more practical if you guys could suggest me a best practice pattern to manage the Session and its HttpModule for NHibernate that is implemented, ready to use and posted somewhere.

Thanks for the insight you could give me about this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buy the book [NHibernate 3.0 Cookbook](https://www.packtpub.com/nhibernate-3-0-cookbook/book#), You can get just the PDF for about 16 quid, BARGIN!

> Buy the book as it goes through how to
>   set up a website using asp.net and asp.net MVC showing how to implement modules for
>   session management. You
>   will not be disappointed and for 16 quid you will save alot of time.

It is based on version 3 but the session management is the same for NHibernate 2.

As a further note I have been usuing Nhibernate for just over a year and found it hard going looking at blogs, tutorials and sample apps etc. Because there is a lot of information regarding NHibernate on the web I found a lot of it is now outdated, you find a lot of contradictions and code that just does not work.

Comment: Hi Rippo. I actually just bought the Pdf and gonna give it a try, hope I can learn how to make a good use of NHibernate. Looks good to me. Thanks a lot!.

Answer (score 0):

The code from the codeproject article is very good and I have used it a lot to learn about setting up a Session factory for NH.

I did not try your code but you should try running their sample exactly as it is, see if that works for you and then start playing with it around.

Good luck

Comment: Hi Variant and thanks for your help. I have tested and ran both samples of CodeProject and worked fine, but the code itself is still kind of obscure to me thats why my NHibernate Session and HttpModule implementations separate layered on my test project is not working yet.